# Ruby gives "Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.3p545 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get Ruby working on a new Windows 8.1 machine. I've downloaded and run `rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p545.exe` from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/, selected the option for it to set the path in the environment, and everything seemed to install just fine. But when I do `ruby -v` I get a popup dialog with the error

```
Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.3p545 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working

A problem has caused the program to stop working correctly.
Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is
available.
```

The Windows log gives me:

```
Faulting application name: ruby.exe, version: 1.9.3.545, time stamp: 0x530be127
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x15c2be1f
Faulting process ID: 0xea8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfc8486f2aeae1
Faulting application path: C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: acdf285b-343b-11e4-be88-a02bb850c78b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

How do I get Ruby working on this computer?

Edit: I need it pretty urgently, so in the absence of responses I'm going to try a factory reset on the computer and starting again from scratch.

Comment: The error code `0xc0000005` is quite popular in the internet. Have you tried some of these steps to fix it? http://compfreakstars.blogspot.com/2011/11/0xc0000005-error-every-day-many.html

It might be some configuration issue in windows.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If not, then please close/delete the question.

Comment: Still an issue. I'm using a different machine to develop Ruby on, but I'd *like* to use that one.

Comment: has anyone solved this problem? I do have a this error when I upgraded to windows 10

Comment: @jargalan using ruby on windows is generally not advised (too much of a hassle to get things working), but please see my answer below - that's what helped me in case of Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `rubyinstaller-2.2.3`, and then `rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p645` on Windows 10 machine. What helped is switching to x64-compatible installer (`rubyinstaller-2.2.3-x64` in my case).